# Reverse engineer website data from highcharts chart

Tags: reverse-engineering

I like to reverse engineer the following highcharts chart: [Bitconnect](https://bitconnect.co/learning-center/bitconnect-bitcoin-price-volatility-software)

This is so I can better calculate my intrest on that site.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Dev tools -> source -> found element id -> searched source for id -> found code below.

```
$('#highchartload-closing-day').highcharts({
 chart: {
  zoomType: 'x'
 },
 title: {
  text: ''
 },
 subtitle: {
  text: 'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in'
 },
 xAxis: [{
  categories: date,
  type: 'datetime',
  crosshair: true
 }],
 yAxis: [{
  labels: {
   format: '{value} %',
   style: {
    color: '#FA890F'
   }
  },
  title: {
   text: 'Rate of interest',
   style: {
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
   }
  }
 }],
 series: [{
  name: 'Rate of Interest',
  type: 'column',
  yAxis: 0,
  data: rate_of_interest,
  color: '#FFC46D',
  tooltip: {
   valueSuffix: ' %'
  }
 }]
});
```